# Missing btc after -zapwallettxes and blockchain rescan

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I sent a transaction in Bitcoin Core and realized that the fee was too low. I waited a few days to see if it would confirm and then wanted to try something else. I read that starting bitcoin core with -zapwallettxes would allow me to resend the transaction with a higher fee, but after doing this I encountered a few problems.

First, the spent and unspent amount to be returned to me from the transaction didn’t seem to be reflected anywhere and were missing from my balance. I attempted to rescan the blockchain, but the transaction confirmed during this time. Now, the transaction and amount I spent are shown in the history, but the excess btc that was unspent and to be returned to me isn’t reflected anywhere. How do I go about getting bitcoin core to recognize that this btc should be back in my balance? Here is the transaction if that helps: 
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/c50fa9c0a1bae6b554fdac1fb7f628f1f8136ed7fea4a1ff2085c6cf727d0895

Second, after the -zapwallettxes and rescan it appears that a bit of additional bitcoin is missing from my balance. This missing bitcoin was not part of the transaction and I haven’t had any other transactions recently (in a few months). I can’t seem to find any cause of the additional missing bitcoin and am honestly more concerned with this chunk than the missing unspent balance in my other issue, which I expect I can be fixed. I would appreciate any tips or suggestions that might help find this missing chunk of bitcoin or get bitcoin core to recognize where it is.

Comment: Have you tried restoring your most recent pre-zap wallet.dat backup on another PC?

Comment: I have not and will give that a shot. Will I need to set up bitcoin core on the other PC and download the blockchain before importing? Wasn’t sure if there is another wallet I could import to faster without downloading the blockchain again.

Comment: See [Is it possible to transfer blockchain data from one machine to another?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/62890/13866) ... You might find an SPV wallet that can import a wallet.dat from Bitcoin core and which (because SPV) doesn't need to download the blockchain. Maybe [Electrum](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/25331/13866)?

Comment: So I made the mistake of not backing the wallet up before the zapwalletstxes. Should I still try this method? After some poking around and using the listunspend command it looks like the unspent bitcoin from the transaction I shared is being accounted for. However, this means there is that much more BTC missing from the wallet. Is this something Zap should be able to cause?

Comment: If I use the listbyreceived and listreceivebyaccount they both show total incoming BTC as 0.728899.  The list unspent command shows 0.08268, which matches my current showing balance. When I list transactions sent it only shows 0.30801 "sent" , but I know it must be much more than this.The problem is that before the ZAP I had about 0.1129 BTC in my balance and now it seems to inexplicably be 0.08268

Comment: As suggested I am now attempting to import my private keys into Electrum. When I dump private keys in bitcoin core the Text file created was incredibly long and there doesn't seem to be a way to copy only the private keys without the rest of the info. If anyone has a tip on how to do this without deleting the extra info (which looks like it may take hours) I would be very appreciative!